# getaddrinfo failed while trying to connect to the database

Tags: mysql, symfony

My hosting provider is giving me a host for my database.

But I can't access this host from my symfony project:

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

here is my .env:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://esoh_metask:mypassword@esoh.myd.infomaniak.com:3306/esoh_task_db
```

When i ping my host, i get an error saying that is it not known.

Comment: Why you asked same question twice? [Symfony Connection to database fail in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62327283/symfony-connection-to-database-fail-in-production)

Comment: I didn't asked well my question..

Comment: So you can use edit function, to fix your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hostname `esoh.myd.infomaniak.com` resolves to the IP address `10.4.27.10`.

`10.*.*.*` addresses are all for private use within data centers. So, if you're trying to run your symfony program on your own machine (office or home) you won't be able to reach that MySQL server -- it's behind a firewall at your vendor.

Ask your vendor for help.